# Bug in perl's autodie.pm?

Tags: perl

I'm expecting:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use autodie;
# autodie in effect here
{
    no autodie;
    # autodie is not in effect here
}
# autodie should be in effect here because of the supposedly lexical scope
# of autodie, but this doesn't die:
open my $i, '<', '/nonexistent';
```

I base that on `perldoc autodie` that says:

> The "autodie" pragma has lexical scope, meaning that functions and
>   subroutines altered with "autodie" will only change their behaviour
>   until the end of the enclosing block, file, or "eval"

Also, `{ no autodie }` (in a scope) is even part of the [SYNOPSIS](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/autodie-2.10/lib/autodie.pm#SYNOPSIS)

`use/no warnings` behaves as I expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
{
    no warnings;
}
# This *does* generate a warning
print undef;
```

Have I missed something or do you agree there a bug in autodie? I didn't find anything in the [autodie buglist](http://rt.cpan.org/NoAuth/Bugs.html?Dist=autodie)

```
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

**EDIT:** I've now filed [a bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=72053)

Comment: Confirmed in Perl v5.14.2 (x86_64).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can reproduce this with v5.10.0 (Debian x86_64) and ActiveState 5.14.2.

Try [this location](https://github.com/pfenwick/autodie/issues) for bug reports.

**EDIT** I tested some: to circumvent the problem until the bug is fixed, you'll need to `use` autodie again:

```
use strict;
use autodie;

do {
    no autodie;
    # ...
} while(0);

use autodie;

open FILE, '<', '/non-existing'; # dies again.
```

Comment: Thanks, yes in my quest for a simple reproducing script I had also discovered that `use autodie;` again was a workaround. Forgot to put it in the post though.

Answer (score 4):

The Synopsis doesn't actually show the directive having a lexical scope, but it is mentioned multiple times elsewhere in the documentation. This is clearly a bug.

The question becomes: Does the bug still exist?

```
$ perl -E'use autodie; say $autodie::VERSION'
2.1001

$ perl -we'use autodie; { no autodie; } open(my $fh, "<", "nonexistant");'

$ perl -we'use autodie; open(my $fh, "<", "nonexistant");'
Can't open 'nonexistant' for reading: 'No such file or directory' at -e line 1

$ perl -we'{ use autodie; } open(my $fh, "<", "nonexistant");'
```

Yes, it does. It's only `no autodie;` that's broken, though. Oddly, that version of autodie is newer than what's currently available on CPAN?! So I downgraded and tried again.

```
$ perl -E'use autodie; say $autodie::VERSION'
2.10

$ perl -we'use autodie; { no autodie; } open(my $fh, "<", "nonexistant");'

$ perl -we'use autodie; open(my $fh, "<", "nonexistant");'
Can't open 'nonexistant' for reading: 'No such file or directory' at -e line 1

$ perl -we'{ use autodie; } open(my $fh, "<", "nonexistant");'
```

Bugs can be filed using autodie's [bug tracker](http://rt.cpan.org/NoAuth/Bugs.html?Dist=autodie).